# PnP PowerShell - How to read default user group from SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, groups, pnp-powershell

I want to export default owner, member & visitor group users and group name in CSV file using PnP PowerShell.

Can someone assist this?

```
$Record=Import-Csv -Path ""
$ResultCollection = @()
foreach($row in $Record)
{
    
    $Site =$row.SourceURL
    $Site = $Site -split("/")
    $Name = $Site[4]
    Write-Host "Connecting source site -----> " $row.SourceURL -ForegroundColor Green
    $srcSite = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $row.SourceURL -UseWebLogin
    Write-Host "Retrieving Default group in source" 
    $srcOwner= Get-PnPGroup -AssociatedOwnerGroup
    Write-Host $srcOwner.Title
    $srcMember= Get-PnPGroup -AssociatedMemberGroup
    Write-Host $srcMember.Title
    $srcVisitor= Get-PnPGroup -AssociatedVisitorGroup
    Write-Host $srcVisitor.Title

    $srcOwnerUsers = $srcOwner.Users | Select Email | % { 
    $srcMemberUsers = $srcMember.Users | Select Email | % { 
    $srcVisitorUsers = $srcVisitor.Users | Select Email | % { 
    
        $Result = New-Object PSObject
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "srcOwner" -Value $srcOwner.Title
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "srcOwnerUsers" -Value $_.Email
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "srcMember" -Value $srcMember.Title
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "srcMemberUsers" -Value $_.Email
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "srcVisitor" -Value $srcVisitor.Title
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "srcVisitorUsers" -Value $_.Email
        $ResultCollection += $Result;
    
    }
    
    }
    
    }
    
     
        $ResultCollection | Export-Csv -Path "" -NoTypeInformation 

}
```

Comment: I have updated my code above. i am facing issue in exporting all the users from individual group. it is fetching one user only from all the group. Not a multiple users. pls someone look into this.

Comment: To isolate the issue, have checked $srcOwner.Users.count? Is it showing 1? You can try adding " -Limit all" swtich, but not sure whether that will help

Comment: I tested again, and it's working for me.  First try "$groupM.Users | select Title, email" to see if you have all the users showing up. email might be blank, so look into the Title as well

Answer (score 0):

Please try below PowerShell.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

function global:Get-SPSite($url)
{
return new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
}

function global:Get-SPWeb($url)
{
    $site= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
    if($site -ne $null)
        {
           $web=$site.OpenWeb();      
        }
     return $web
}

 $URL="site collection URL"

 $site = Get-SPSite $URL

 #Write the Header to "Tab Separated Text File"
    "Site Name`t  URL `t Group Name `t User Account `t User Name `t E-Mail" | out-file "c:\UsersandGroupsRpt.txt"
     
 #Iterate through all Webs
  foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
  {
    #Write the Header to "Tab Separated Text File"
    "$($web.title) `t $($web.URL) `t  `t  `t `t " | out-file "c:\UsersandGroupsRpt.txt" -append
     #Get all Groups and Iterate through   
     foreach ($group in $Web.groups)
     {
            "`t  `t $($Group.Name) `t   `t `t " | out-file "c:\UsersandGroupsRpt.txt" -append
            #Iterate through Each User in the group
                   foreach ($user in $group.users)
                    {
                       #Exclude Built-in User Accounts
                if(($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\authenticated users") -and ($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "sharepoint\system") -and ($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\local service"))
                {
                            "`t  `t  `t  $($user.LoginName)  `t  $($user.name) `t  $($user.Email)" | out-file "c:\UsersandGroupsRpt.txt" -append
                         }
                    }
     }
   }
write-host "Report Generated at c:\UsersandGroups.txt"
```

Reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/export-sharepoint-users-and-groups-to-excel-using-powershell.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **PnP PowerShell** version of the script to get **Default** Groups' and Users' information from an on-premise site collection for the root and sub webs that have unique permissions. The output is saved into a *CSV file.You can modify it as needed.

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\SharePointPnPPowerShell2013\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShell2013" -Verbose

$global:cred = Get-Credential

$SiteURL = "https://WebApp.com/sites/SiteCollName/"
$CSVFilePath="C:\Users\GroupAndUser.csv"


<#================================================================================
Functions:

ProcessWeb($web) - get the defaut groups of a given site
ProcessGroupUser([object] $group, [string]$url, [string]$type) - Process Groups and Users and stores in a global array

#>


Function ProcessWeb([object]$web)  
{  
     #change the context to the web
     $conW=Connect-PnPOnline -Url $web.Url -Credentials $global:cred 
    
     $url=$web.Url

     Write-host "Processing Site: " $web.Title " Url: " $url
     
     # Owner Group
     $groupOwner = Get-PnPGroup -AssociatedOwnerGroup             
     ProcessGroupUser $groupOwner $url "OWNER"
     

     # Member Group     
     $groupM= Get-PnPGroup -AssociatedMemberGroup
     ProcessGroupUser $groupM $url  'MEMBER'
      

     # Visitor Group
     $groupV = Get-PnPGroup -AssociatedVisitorGroup
     ProcessGroupUser $groupV $url 'VISITOR'
    
}  

Function ProcessGroupUser([object] $group, [string]$url, [string]$type)
{
     $users=$group.Users  #Title and Email
     
     if($users.count -eq 0)   {
      
         $groupuser= [PSCustomObject][ordered] @{             
                   GroupName=$group.Title
                   GroupType=$type
                   UserName="NO USER FOUND"
                   UserEmail="NO USER FOUND"
                   SiteUrl= $url               
                    } 

        $global:GroupAndUserData+=$groupuser
     }
     else  {
     
          Write-host "Processing Groups and Users for URL: " $url      
        
            foreach($user in $users) 
              {
                $groupuser= [PSCustomObject][ordered] @{            
                   GroupName=$group.Title
                   GroupType=$type
                   UserName=$user.Title
                   UserEmail=$user.Email
                   SiteUrl= $url               
                        }
                                            
                $global:GroupAndUserData+=$groupuser 
            
               } 
       }     

}

#================================================================================

#Initialize global variable to store groups and users
$global:GroupAndUserData=@()

#Connect to the Site Collection
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $global:cred

#Process the root web First
$rootWeb= Get-PnPWeb
ProcessWeb $rootWeb 


#All the Webs that have unique permission
#Getting all sub webs with unique permission flag 
$subWebs =Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse -Includes HasUniqueRoleAssignments

foreach($subweb in $subWebs)
{
   # Process all sub webs with UNIQUE permission
   if($subweb.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $true)
   {
        ProcessWeb $subweb
   }
   else
   {
    
    Write-host "site" $subweb.Url "is inheriting permission from parent"

   }
}


#================================================================================
#Export the data to CSV
$global:GroupAndUserData | Export-Csv $CSVFilePath -NoTypeInformation
 
Write-host -f Green "Groups Report Generated Successfully!"
```

Comment: pls check my updated code. I am unable to retrieve all the user from the group